# Can I deploy Strapi app without npm installed?

Tags: rest, npm, strapi

I have already purchased business hosting from mochahost and it does not have nodejs or npm
In my local machine I have an strapi api configured and I want to use it on my hosting. My question is, with few config changes, can I simply copy all files/deploy it on the Mochahost web server without the npm build command? If not what are my options?

Note all I need is the api's (CRUD) from the STRAPI application and get it to run there.

than you!

Comment: Yeah, you must have node environment running for Strapi to work in deployment

Comment: Thank you! My hosting does not support it, having said that, can I download the npm package and save it to work?

Comment: No your hosting would need to have node environment running.  Checkout Render. You can host your Strapi app for free.  https://render.com/